# The word "lad" in the south of the U.S

Tags: north-american-english

Is there any possibility that a farmer from the southern part of the U.S. will use the word "lad", or is it completely 'Brit'? the context is naming a pet (a mule) "lad".

Comment: Unless you want the pet's name to be quintessentially American.

Comment: In Britain 'lad' is more often heard north of the great Severn-Wash linguistic divide. 'Boy', 'fellow', 'chap' or 'bloke' are more the way of the south of England, but everyone understands and uses 'lad', even some Cockneys.

Comment: Did you actually mean 'pet' as opposed to 'livestock'? And did you mean 'name' (in the way a collie was named *Lassie*) rather than 'address' (as in "Come on lad, pull the thing")?

Comment: It is a name of a mule "Orphan Lad", but no doubt that it is his name.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming pets.

Comment: - 'lad' is not a word used in any variety of AmE (southern  included). It might be understood when heard, but it would be also understood to be a Britishism. - so this is motivated by the name of a pet? Anything goes there.

Comment: I am watching the 80s movie Porky's and the policeman with a southern accent calls some young lawbreakers "lads." I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to naming pets, anything goes, so I'd say that the simple answer to your question "Is there any possibility...?" is "Yes."

Comment: The farmer could be from the north of England, or have a family member who was. It's possible to write a back-story behind a name.